# Import multiple Python scripts based on different virtualenvs with different versions of Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a main script which has to perform some operations importing two old python scripts. Script 1 is based on Django 1.4, script 2 is based on Django 1.7.

Main

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import script_1
import script_2
```

Script_1

```
# ...
# activate venv
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.foo/django1.4/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

# Set up the Django Enviroment
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

Script_2

```
# ...
# activate venv
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.foo/django1.7/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

# Set up the Django Enviroment
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myModule.settings")
django.setup()
```

In the way above, the second virtualenv is not loaded. Is there a way to deal with multiple virtualenvs when importing?

Comment: Do you really need to import both scripts? Why not just execute them with `subprocess` (or use a shell script to execute both scripts)?

Comment: yes, such workarounds are a possible solution. I'm just wondering if there was a "way" to avoid virtualenvs collision directly in Python. Probably not (except for `subprocess`).

Comment: Trying to import two different versions of Django from two different virtualenvs sounds like a bad idea. Without more details, executing both scripts sounds like a better approach, not a workaround.